# PHP Fail on solaris 10

Tags: php, solaris, solaris-10

I'm trying to get PHP to work on a Solaris 10 machine, PHP was installed successfully without throwing any errors using the below configuration:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/lib --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds --without-pgsql --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local --with-pcre-dir=/usr/local --with-gettext=/usr/local --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local --with-gd --with-xpm-dir=/usr/local --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local --with-png-dir=/usr/local --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --enable-mbstring --enable-exif --enable-soap --enable-zip --enable-ftp --enable-mysqlnd --disable-zend-signals --disable-static
```

However when I start my Apache server, and accessing php info page:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

I get a blank page..

when running php -m , i get a lot of fatal errors about many failing libraries, below is the output:

```
[root@mm]#php -m
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libreadline.so.6: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libmysqlclient.so.18: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libsybdb.so.5: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libmcrypt.so.4: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libltdl.so.7: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: /usr/sfw/lib/amd64//libfreetype.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libX11.so.6: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libxcb.so.1: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libXau.so.6: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libXdmcp.so.6: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libpng14.so.14: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libjpeg.so.8: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libdb-4.8.so: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libgdbm.so.3: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libpcre.so.1: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libcrypto.so.0.9.8: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libssl.so.0.9.8: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libgssapi_krb5.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libkrb5.so.3: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libk5crypto.so.3: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libcom_err.so.3: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libcurl.so.4: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libldap-2.4.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: liblber-2.4.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libintl.so.8: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libsasl2.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libssh2.so.1: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libiodbc.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: libiconv.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
ld.so.1: php: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/local/bin/php: symbol rl_library_version: referenced symbol not found
Killed
```

Thnaks

Comment: try `php -v` and check version of it

Comment: i tried it and its throwing the same above error.

Comment: What's the output from `ldd -s /usr/local/bin/php`?  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/ldd-1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the helpful information, i managed to resolve the issue by adding:

```
LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
PHPIniDir "/usr/local/php/etc/" //this is the location of the PHP configurations file
```

to the Apache configuration file, then restarting the Apache server..

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file there is this directive:

```
extension_dir =
```

it should point to where your extensions are, the ones it is complaining about. It doesn't seem to be pointing anywhere where it would find your php libraries, thus it is failing.

In addition, you should check your error log for any errors, and I recommend turning on `display_startup_errors` directive in your configuration to see the critical issues when php module is started together with apache.

Comment: thank you for the answer, the current directory is set to: `; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"
` .. any idea if this needs to be changed?

Comment: @AliJaber you should be able to tell that, since you've done the installation. Should it be? Is it pointing to the directory containing your extensions?

Comment: Also, I think all the lines you pasted are comments, so it's commented out?